# DetailDisclosureButton

Tags: iphone

What is the way to to add some text with DetailDisclosureButton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add text to a UITableViewCell:

```
cell.textLabel.text = @"foo";
```

To add a disclosure button:

```
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
```

If you want to change the disclosure button to include text somehow, subclass UITableViewCell and use that instead.